# Passing ef query to view

Tags: c#

This works:

```
var model =
   (from t in _db.Tickets
   from p in _db.Cust
   where t.Id == 5 && t.Id == p.cust_id
   orderby t.Id descending
   select new tks_custs
   {
       Tks = t,
       Custs = p
   });
```

But I want to achieve like this to use group by:

```
var model = _db.Tickets
    .Join(_db.Cust,
        t => t.Id,
        w => w.cust_id,
        (t, w) => new { Tks = t, Custs = w })
    .Where(t => t.Tks.Id == 5).OrderByDescending(w => w.Tks.Id)
    .GroupBy(t => t.Tks.Name).ToList();
```

My view declaration is currently:

```
 @model IQueryable<test.ViewModels.tks_custs>
```

Comment: error is. view accepts iqueryable but an db query is passed through

Comment: Pass ViewModel not Model....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your VieModel object (`tks_custs`) same way like you do it your first query. Now you try to pass DB model (actually not BD model, but anonymouse `IGrouping` object).

It should be something like this:

```
var model = _db.Tickets
            .Join(_db.Cust,
                t => t.Id,
                w => w.cust_id,
                (t, w) => new { Tks = t, Custs = w })
            .Where(t => t.Tks.Id == 5).OrderByDescending(w => w.Tks.Id)
            .GroupBy(t => t.Tks.Name).ToList()
            .Select(x => new tks_custs //here you creating your ViewModel
            {
                Tks = x.FirstOrDefailt().Tks,
                Custs = x.FirstOrDefailt().Custs 
            });
```

You may notice `FirstOrDefailt()`. You need it becouse after `GroupBy` you may have many entities in group.